# Phrase for apologizing to a stranger when messaging him unexpectedly?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or a phrase to use when I start talking to/chatting with someone expert in some field, he doesn't know me or know me a little, but we never chatted with each other.
I want to ask him a question related to the field he is experienced at.
it's like:

> Excuse me for ***jumping over*** you inbox , but I think you are
>   the best one who can help me in this...

but I don't think "*jumping over*" is the correct phrase, as I invented it

Comment: "Excuse me for arriving unannounced in your inbox, but...."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"out of nowhere"**  or **"out of the blue"** can sometimes work, although they are more frequently used for the other person to describe your contact.

> "Hey,  I apologize for contacting you **out of the blue**, but my name is John Doe I live two blocks away on Elm Dr. I've seen you using a tall extension ladder.  Could I ask a favor to borrow the ladder for a few hours Sunday ? I'd hope I could return a favor in the future."

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+nowhere

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+the+blue

Answer (score 1):

### Circumventing

1. to avoid having to comply with (something) especially through cleverness 
   • *employees who try to circumvent the company's dress code*
2. to avoid by going around • *circumvented the traffic jam by taking an alternate route*

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/circumventing)

Some others you might consider are *bypassing*, *leapfrogging*, *sidestepping*